# the previous fragment is not hide why?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to add fragment,i set previous background #ffffff the layout hide when i go next fragment but the items in previous fragment in working in next fragment, the fragment not hide why?

this is my code

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if(isSearchHappened){
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transection=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transection.hide(WorkOrderFragment.this);
                DeliveryProcessFragment deliveryProcessFragment=new DeliveryProcessFragment();
                deliveryProcessFragment.jobBeans = searchArayList.get(position);
                transection.add(R.id.frame, deliveryProcessFragment);
                transection.commit();
            }else {
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transection=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transection.hide(WorkOrderFragment.this);
                DeliveryProcessFragment deliveryProcessFragment=new DeliveryProcessFragment();
                deliveryProcessFragment.jobBeans = arrayList.get(position);
                transection.add(R.id.frame, deliveryProcessFragment);
                transection.commit();
            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: `transection.add` does not remove old fragment from container. It adds new one on top of another. To remove previous, use `transection.replace`

Comment: when i am using transaction.replace and than come back again previous fragment,  data is not showing

Comment: that's another problem.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
FragmentManagerfragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransactionfragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
  myFrag=newMyFrag();
  myFrag.setSpecialText("Fragtime:"+System.currentTimeMillis());
  myFragList.add(myFrag);
  fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.myFrame,myFrag);
  fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
else {
  if((myFragList.size()-1)>=0){
    FragmentManagerfragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransactionfragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    MyFraglastFrag=myFragList.get(myFragList.size()-1);
    fragmentTransaction.remove(lastFrag);
    myFragList.remove(lastFrag);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
  }
}
```